# MobileFirst Server issue while installing Anywhere 7.6.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, maximo, maximo-anywhere, worklight-runtime

While installing Maximo anywhere 7.6.2 I am getting below issue. I am able to access worklight console and Appcenter console without any issues.

Attached screenshots of the issue.

The issue occurring while configuring Stand-alone mobile first server host, port, context root, etc. Because of this issue I am unable to deploy runtime.

Issue:

> http://hostname:9081/wladmin that was specified could not be bound please specify valid url.
>
> http://hostname:9081/applicationcenter that was specified could not be bound please specify valid url

[image]

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not clear how Maximo installation works. Since you mention being able to access the console, I assume wladmin is already in place.  If that is the case, are you trying another standalone installation and is that failing for absence of wladmin ( because it is not already installed)? The other possibility is the context root itself. Are you sure you have "wladmin" and not "worklightadmin" installed?

Comment: I am able to access worklight console using wasadmin user..but while installing maximo anywhere on worklight server the default context root displaying wladmin..not sure where I have to configure to allow wladmin

Comment: Issue fixed by modifying virtual host

Comment: can you please write out the answer so that any other user facing the same issue can use it as the solution? Specifically, what you modified to get things working again.